# Difficulties creating image upload option

Tags: php, arrays, image, file

I created a test page that to learn how to upload an image. I am trying to save the image into a folder I created called image, then in my database, store the file name of that image, to help with space. Right now the image filename isn't storing, instead the word `Array` is storing. I do get an error for that, as well as others. After I click upload, I get the following errors:

> **Warning: move_uploaded_file(image/picturetest.jpg):** failed to open stream: No such file or directory in /home4/fdfsfs/public_html/example.com/img_test.php on line 34
>
> **Warning: move_uploaded_file():** Unable to move '/tmp/phpUg7p4D' to 'image/picturetest.jpg' in /home4/fdsfafa/public_html/example.com/img_test.php on line 34

```
There was an error!
```

> **Notice: Array to string conversion in /home4/fdsfaf/public_html/example.com/img_test.php on line 59

Line 34 is:

```
if (move_uploaded_file($tmp_name, $destinationFolder.$filename)) {
```

Line 59 is:

```
$stmt->execute();
```

Full Script:

```
$filename = $_FILES['file']['name'];
//$filesize = $_FILES['file']['size'];
//$filetype = $_FILES['file']['type'];
$tmp_name = $_FILES['file']['tmp_name'];
$file_error = $_FILES['file']['error'];

if(isset($_POST['create'])){
    $file = $filename;
    $file = $_FILES['file'];
    //$file = "productpics/". $_FILES['file']['name']; // save the filename
}else {
    echo "error!";
    }
            
if (isset($filename )) {
    if (!empty($filename)) {
                
        $destinationFolder = 'image/';
                
        if (move_uploaded_file($tmp_name, $destinationFolder.$filename)) {
            echo 'Uploaded!';
        } else {
            echo 'There was an error!';
        }
                
    } else {
        echo 'Please choose a file.';
    }
}


//Connection
$con = mysqli_connect("localhost","","","");
    if (mysqli_connect_errno()) {
        printf("Connect failed: %s\n", mysqli_connect_error());
        exit();
    }

    if ($stmt = mysqli_prepare($con, "INSERT INTO image (img) VALUES (?)")) {

                    /* bind parameters for markers */
                    $stmt->bind_param('s', $file);

                    /* execute query */
                    $stmt->execute();
                    //if(!$stmt->execute()){trigger_error("there was an error....".$con->error, E_USER_WARNING);}

                /* close statement */
                mysqli_stmt_close($stmt);
                    echo "Success!";
                } else {
                    echo "Failed!";
                }
                
$result = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * FROM image");
    if($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
        if($row['img'] == ""){
            echo "<img src='images/default_pic.png' alt='No Picture'>";
        } else {
            echo "<img src='images/".$row['img']."' alt='Profile Picture'>";
        }
            echo "<br><br><br><br>";
    }
?>


<form action="" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <input type="file" name="file" class="inputbarfile">
    <input type="submit" name="create" id="signinButton" value="Upload">
</form>
```

Does anyone see what I am doing wrong with this???

Comment: At the very top of your script you write `$file = $_FILES['file'];` that will be why you are writing `Array` to your database here `$stmt->bind_param('s', $file);`

Comment: You will want to save this to your database likely: `$destinationFolder.$filename`

Comment: @Rasclatt I'm confused as to what you are saying to do.

Comment: As for the first warning, are you sure you made the folder for the image storage in the right place? Try doing `mkdir()` to create a folder

Comment: At the top, you assign `$file = $_FILES['file'];` which is assigning the `$_FILES['file']` array to the variable `$file`. At the bottom you try to write that array to your database without processing the array so it writes `Array`

Comment: I created a folder called images. The image is not saving to it though, so would that be why the error is there?

Comment: The warning is saying to directory or file found, so it's possible it's trying to save to a folder in a different spot than you intended

Comment: @Rasclatt How would you suggest to process the array first?

Comment: Well you are probably trying to store the final destination, which would be: `$destinationFolder.$filename`. Put that into your database

Comment: @Rasclatt ... You were right about the destination folder location. I had 'image' instead of 'images'. I changed that and now the image is saving into my destination folder. Now, I just need for this to save as the filename.

Comment: So, this `$destinationFolder.$filename` instead of `$file`?

Comment: `$stmt->bind_param('s', $destinationFolder.$filename);`

Comment: I get a fatal error when trying to do that... `Fatal error: Cannot pass parameter 2 by reference in`

Comment: Try assigning it to a variable first `$finalDest = $destinationFolder.$filename; $stmt->bind_param('s', $finalDest);` I don't use `mysqli_`, rather `PDO`, so am not sure about troubleshooting `mysqli_`.

Comment: From what I have read, that may fix the Fatal Error issue.

Comment: Perfect! It worked like a charm! Random quick question. Upon page load before I even try to submit a photo, my page says "error!Success!" Why are my else statements showing those before I even try to process anything?

Comment: Also, if you want to create an answer, I will accept it.

Comment: Let me do an answer that may help you a bit more with all this.

Comment: That'd be great! Thanks!

Comment: Yeah, give me a few minutes more, I am finishing up here.

Comment: If you have any questions or issues with my answer, let me know. I tried it on my database and it does everything you were looking for.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So to sort of "redo" what you have, I have broken it down into parts (*functions*). It's basically the same, however each part is broken down so it's 1) easier to manage each part 2) easier to troubleshoot 3) easier to add error handling to.

```
<?php
// If you make a file function, you can change where things are saved
// You can also change the destination (for portability)
function UploadFile($fileArray = array(), $destinationFolder = 'image/')
    {
        $filename       =   $fileArray['file']['name'];
        $tmp_name       =   $fileArray['file']['tmp_name'];
        $filesize       =   $fileArray['file']['size'];
        $file_error     =   $fileArray['file']['error'];
        $file           =   $fileArray['file'];
        // Save all the default data.
        // Success and error should be set by default to fail
        $return['error']        =   true;
        $return['success']      =   false;
        $return['file']['dest'] =   $destinationFolder.$filename;
        $return['file']['size'] =   $filesize;

        if($file_error == 0)
            $return['error']    =   false;
        // I added a directory creation function so you don't have to 
        // manually make folders. This will do it for you.
        if(!is_dir($destinationFolder))
            mkdir($destinationFolder,0755,true);
        // If your filename is not empty, return success or fail of upload
        if (!empty($filename))
            $return['success']  =   (move_uploaded_file($tmp_name, $destinationFolder.$filename));  

        return $return; 
    }

// Create a function that quickly returns your connection   
function Connection()
    {
        //Connection
        $con = mysqli_connect("localhost","","","");
            if (mysqli_connect_errno()) {
                printf("Connect failed: %s\n", mysqli_connect_error());
                exit();
            }

        return $con;
    }

// Create a save-to-database function so it's easier and reusable
function SaveToDb($con,$filename = false)
    {
        // Return fail immediately if the connection is false
        // or the image name is invalid
        if(empty($filename) || !$con)
            return false;

        if ($stmt = mysqli_prepare($con, "INSERT INTO image (img) VALUES (?)")) {
                $stmt->bind_param('s', $filename);
                $stmt->execute();
                mysqli_stmt_close($stmt);

                return true;
            }

        return false;
    }

// This just gets the image from the destination column. Not the most
// efficient, but you can change it to fetch by id or whatever is unique
function getPhoto($con,$dest)
    {
        $result = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * FROM `image` where `img` = '$dest'");
        if($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))
            return $row;

        return 0;
    }
```

**To use:**

```
// Make sure all functions above are include here

// Get the database connection
$con        =   Connection();
// Check for post   
if(isset($_POST['create'])) {
        // Try uploading
        $upload =   UploadFile($_FILES);
        // If upload fails
        if(!$upload['success'])
            echo '<h3>Sorry, an error occurred</h3>';
        else {
                // You could add error handling here based on the results of 
                // each function's success or failure below.

                // Try to save it
                $saveToDb   =   SaveToDb($con,$upload['file']['dest']);
                // Get the profile from image name
                $profPic    =   ($saveToDb)? getPhoto($con,$upload['file']['dest']) : false; ?>

                <img src="<?php echo (!empty($profPic) && $profPic != 0)? $profPic['img'] : "default_pic.png"; ?>" alt="<?php echo (!empty($profPic) && $profPic != 0)? "Profile Picture" : "No Picture"; ?>" />
                <?php
            }
    }
?>
```

Comment: First off, thanks a lot for expanding in such great detail! Alright, so this takes away the messages I was getting obviously. This is definitely over my skill level, so I am trying to sink it all in. Whenever I upload a photo, it shows the image in a very large version on the page, so the real size of it. Is there anyway to get the image to only appear in the 'your image' box? You can see what it is doing on my site if you want. I am just playing around with this now, so feel free to upload an image if it helps. realtorcatch.com/test_test_img

Comment: Yes, you can make it appear in a certain image box at the correct size using CSS -> `max-width` and/or `max-height` To make it appear in the box you want, you just change the logic and put the `<img src="<?php echo (!empty($profPic) && $profPic != 0)? $profPic['img'] : "default_pic.png"; ?>" alt="<?php echo (!empty($profPic) && $profPic != 0)? "Profile Picture" : "No Picture"; ?>" />` outside the `if`

Comment: Idealy you will want to save the user's information to a session to populate that field.

Comment: Are my changes correct? To save the user's info to a session, would I just be saving the picture, so their current pic displays?

Comment: What you'd do is when the user logs in you would save to session the users id, username, maybe a couple other variables, then when Saving to disk the users image, save a reference to them in your database that corresponds to their image. Then you can pull it when they go to their profile.

Comment: Thanks a lot! I will definitely have to play around with all of this, to learn it and modify, but I appreciate all of your help!

Comment: Yeah the functions will help you keep separation-of-duty and reusability as a bonus. The functions are basically just little wrappers for your code so you can keep things nice and clean and if you want to upload on a different page, you can basically  use the same upload function, maybe just changing the upload directory as an argument. Learning about functions (and classes) was basically the single-most useful (overall) improvement to my own work that I did. It will make your life easier if you learn how to properly make and use functions.

Comment: I will definitely have to look into that! That and PDO will be my next things to learn. Thanks again!

Answer (score -1):

You need to turn the array into string. [Here](http://www.w3schools.com/php/func_string_implode.asp) is an example.